# Finiteness of the particular solution of a 2nd order ODE at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The general solution, $y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)$, of a nonhomogeneous second order ODE involves the solution to the related homogenous ODE, $y_h (x) = A y_1(x) + B y_2(x)$, and a particular solution, $y_p(x)$. A particular solution, $y_p$, to the nonhomogeneous ODE can be constructed through the variation of parameters and it is given by:

$y_p(x) = y_1(x) \int \frac{y_2(x) f(x)}{W(x)} dx - y_2(x) \int \frac{y_1(x) f(x)}{W(x)} dx$

where $W(x)$ is the Wronskian and $f(x)$ is the nonhomogeneous term (source term) in the underlying ODE. In some problems one of the independent solutions of the homogenous ODE, lets say $y_1$, blows up at the origin and therefore A must be zero if the solution is to be finite everywhere. Here are my questions: Is there a guarantee that the particular solution $y_p(x)$ wont blow up at the origin? Can you refer me to the literature on this matter? If it can blow up then what is to be done about it when the solution must be finite everywhere?